# Shell builtin - bind

Tags: bash

### Edit:

This was due to my PS1 Variable being jacked up (refer to answer section for solution).

### Issue:

It seems that I am missing a serious concept of the shell builtin `bind`:

```
Mac Shell: ~/> $ bind '"4~":"for x in $(); do blah; done"'
# This is my F12 key
Mac Shell: ~/> $ fx in $(); do blah; doneor
```

- This serves no purpose for me other than learning how to use bind.

Note: The `or` in `for` along with the `::space::` following `for` ends up going to the end of the line.

### Question:

**Can anybody point me in the correct direction as to what I am doing wrong?** I checked `man bash # shell builtin section` and `man bind` to no avail.

### Bash version:

```
Mac Shell: ~/> $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with your case. For me its giving exact results   bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: That command is working for me in both iTerm and Terminal on El Capitan.

Comment: Do either/both of you have differing character maps for your F12 key? I have tried escaping the tilda and end up with the same result. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused due to improperly quoted ANSI color schemes in my PS1 variable. Essentially I needed `\[` & `\]` around each color code to prevent a miscalculation of bash prompt length.

Thanks everyone for attempting to help me with this issue.

Comment: Was there actually any issue specific to the bind command *at all*? If not, you might consider deleting or rewriting your question, as it's not likely to be useful to others seeking help with the bind builtin in its current state.

Comment: I thought that it was due to the output that I was seeing but I now see that this was caused by being a dummy with my PS1 variable.